# how to explain the thinkscript grammar？

Tags: thinkscript

```
def trend = if isNaN(reversal[1]) then 0 else if reversal[1] != reversal then 0 else trend[1] * (1 - smf) + cpc * smf;

def agg_count = compoundvalue(1, if timeInterval != timeInterval[1] then (getValue(agg_count, 1) + timeInterval - timeInterval[1]) % aggMultiplier else getValue(agg_count, 1), 0);

def isPeriodRolled = compoundValue(1, periodIndx != periodIndx[1], yes);
```

> “reversal[1] != reversal ”,“timeInterval != timeInterval[1]”,"periodIndx != periodIndx[1]" and so on.
>
> What dose the “X != X[1]”   really mean in thinkscript?

Answer (score 2):

`X != X[1]` in thinkScript means `X` not equal to `X` from the bar before.

---

thinkScript operates in "bars". Each bar represents a timeframe, say days on a daily chart or minutes on an intraday chart for example. A bar can also represent a "tick". For this explanation, I'll use days: each bar representing one trading day.

thinkScript processes in a hidden loop: almost all code is processed once for each loop. The loop index, say, is the number of bars in a period. For example, if you're looking at a 14-day chart, then the code would run similarly to the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) { ... your thinkScript code here ... }
```

However, some things are switched up. In thinkScript, the bar count goes from the left to the right: bar 1 is the furthest back in time (or *left*most on the chart), bar 2 is the next bar toward now, and so on; ending with bar 14, say, being the actual current bar (using the 14-day chart, for example).

When one is using subscripts, however, it's actually opposite. `X` or `X[0]` represents the current bar that's processing - whichever is furthest to the *right*. `X[1]` means the bar before the current one, `X[2]` means 2 bars before the current one, and so on - to `X[13]`, in our 14-day chart, being the 14th day back in the data. Of course, a 50-day chart, say, could go from `X` back to `X[49]`, and so on.

Alternatively, in thinkScript you can actually look at *future* bars using *negative* subscripts: `X[-1]` is the *next* day in the chart, `X[-2]` is 2 days forward in the chart.

**In summary**: `X` is the value of `X` at the *current* bar and `X[1]` is the value of `X` at the bar *before* the current bar.